# what time to call flatlist scrollToEnd method would work

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I set flatlist's data in the constructor, and call flatlist scrollToEnd in the componentDidMount method, I think it should scroll to end, but it did't. And I click one button to call scrollToEnd  method, the flatlist scroll to end.

So I want to know when should I call flatlist's method to change it without click.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `scrollToEnd` with timeout

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.refs.list.scrollToEnd();
  }, 100);
}
```

When you call without timeout your `FlatList` not render at that time so `scrollToEnd` not working

Comment: It works, but I guess there should  be some place or set a flag instead of setTimeout